# Logback configuration into Java project

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, logging, logback

I'm using logback to save all my INFO into log file and every day I would like to save this file in a specific folder `archived`
This is how I have configured it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${CATALINA_HOME}/logs/DartFleetViewer.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${CATALINA_HOME}/logs/archived/DartFleetViewer.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                        </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>

    <!-- <appender name="FILE-ERROR"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/error.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            rollover daily
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                        </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender> -->

    <!-- Send logs to both console and file audit -->
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

    <!-- <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
    </root> -->

</configuration>
```

The odd thing is that I find this in my folder

[image]

almost all of the files are empty or with few code lines, for example I don't find nothing about yesterday, In the last file I only find

```
2016-08-02 02:18:06 - SCHEDULED ACTIVITY TO DELETE OLD NOTIFICATIONS
2016-08-02 05:18:06 - SCHEDULED ACTIVITY TO DELETE OLD NOTIFICATIONS
2016-08-02 08:18:06 - SCHEDULED ACTIVITY TO DELETE OLD NOTIFICATIONS
```

This is information about today and not yesterday.
Furthermore yesterday I had some errors, warnings and a lot of info log.
Do you see some error in my configuration file?

***UPDATE:*** 
Since I receive warning during deployment I have changed my logback configuration in order to avoid all warning and I use only time rollback. It seems to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${CATALINA_HOME}/logs/DartFleetViewer.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${CATALINA_HOME}/logs/archived/DartFleetViewer.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>     
            <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Send logs to both console and file audit -->
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

    <!-- <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
    </root> -->

</configuration>
```

Comment: "Yesterday" is in DartFleetViewer.2016-08-01.0.log ? That would be totally expected. You used SizeAndTimeBased - meaning: Roll if size reaches maxFileSize **or** when the time-pattern in the fileNamePattern does not fit current time any more. In your case: roll daily even if maxSize is not reached.

Comment: yes but in yesterday file I find information about today and not all information that yesterday I saw in linux console.

Comment: OK, **that's** odd ... Are all outputs to the console coming through the logging system? Or are there outputs to System.out or System.err ? To avoid this, I usually do not use a console appender but issue a tail -f on the logfile from a bash shell. (Or on windows get-content ... -Wait in Powershell)

Comment: Yes, I don't use System.out but only LOG.error or LOG.info. Often the log files have information about the day after, I don't know why. To show information in real time I use tail command on catalina.out

Comment: Ah, so catalina.out will include more output than your file. But I wonder how that date-barrier is broken ...

Comment: I don't know, may it depends on ThreadPoolTaskExecutor? All log about  yestarday is lost

Comment: I doubt that an Executor can cause this. Maybe try a size-only rolling policy and see if all logs are written as expected. If there are logs missing, too then it's not the appender but something else.

Comment: Is your logback version prior to 1.1.7? The doc mentions SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP ... Maybe you should switch to ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy

Comment: I have 1.1.3 but I can update this maven dependency

Comment: I suggest you have a look into the docs: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy and decide for yourself.